# I am getting Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 when making API request from iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurlconnection

Hi I am getting `Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2` in 
`- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` delegate method.

This is very strange, all my other APIs are working.
The only thing is that in this API I am sending large sized arrays in POST Request.
Why such errors happen?

Comment: Can you please provide more details of your code?

Comment: Actually in backGround thread i am creating Array , and then i am calling main thread and sending request with that Array,
Its like: function1 calls function2 in background thread and creating array
as array created in same function i am dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() and calling the API

Comment: I mean, put the whole code in your question (by editing it and formatting it appropriately). With the very few elements you're giving, it's difficult to help.

Comment: hi roaming please check my code below

Answer (score -1):

```
Its my modal class:
Global Variable-
NSString *number;
NSArray * globalParsedcontactsArray;

//Calling Function1 from another class in background thread
-(void)function1{
//Database Operation:
NSMutableArray *parsedNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
number = @"some value";
for loop
{
[parsedNumberArray addObject:localVar1];
}

 globalParsedcontactsArray = parsedNumberArray;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self requestAPIInMainThread : globalParsedcontactsArray];

    });
}


+(void) requestAPIInMainThread :(NSArray *)array
{
    NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:number,array ,nil];
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects@"key1", @"key2",nil];
   NSDictionary *Dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
   [self requestAPI:Dictionary];
}

and in my networkConnection delegate didFailwith error i am getting POSIX error 2, no such files
```